# Select from table only with no records on the second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables

**TABLE1** (ID_OWNER, NAME)

```
1,JOHN
1,ELVIS
1,MICHAEL
1,KELVIN
```

**TABLE2** (ID_OWNER, NAME)

```
1,KELVIN
```

My conditions are:

Only return the records from **TABLE 1** if there isn't records from the same owner in **TABLE 2**

**But if there are records in TABLE_2 must retrieve only the records from TABLE_2**

I tried

```
SELECT  
    COALESCE(TB1.NAME,TB2.NAME)
FROM 
    TABLE_2 TB2
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLE_1 TB1 ON TB1.OWNER_ID = TB2.OWNER_ID 
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                FROM TABLE_2 TB2_SUB 
                                WHERE TB2_SUB.OWNER_ID = TB1.OWNER_ID)
WHERE 
    TB2.OWNER_ID = 1
```

but when `TABLE_2` doesn't have records the query doesn't retrieve records.

Comment: WHAT A NICE FORMATTING

Comment: Move TB2.OWNER_ID = 1 to the where predicate. When you put it in the where clause it turning your left join into an inner join. :)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to put this requirment but if there are records in TABLE_2 must retrieve only the records from TABLE_2

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating your code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2
                 WHERE ID_OWNER = T1.ID_OWNER)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  id_owner NOT IN (SELECT id_owner FROM table2)
```